# Hive crashing with java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: hadoop, hive

Running hive 3.1.1 against Hadoop 3.2.0 crashes when running 'select * from employee' with

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedMap does not implement the requested interface java.util.NavigableMap
```

Commands like `show tables` all run fine and data is loaded ok from the CLI as well.

Checked various other commands and e.g. data is loaded etc. Uses MySQL as metastore with `MySQL-connector-java-5.1.47.jar`. The only other observation is that sometimes I get

```
WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
```

which other people seem to get as well and seems not to impact me here.
Anybody seen this as well? Help greatly appreciated ...

```
2019-04-02 16:24:41,643 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Done cleaning up thread local RawStore
2019-04-02 16:24:41,645 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=fdai0145  ip=unknown-ip-addr      cmd=Done cleaning up thread local RawStore
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedMap does not implement the requested interface java.util.NavigableMap
        at org.apache.calcite.schema.Schemas.gatherLattices(Schemas.java:498)
        at org.apache.calcite.schema.Schemas.getLatticeEntries(Schemas.java:492)
        at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.init(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver$1.onConnectionInit(Driver.java:109)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:139)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at org.apache.calcite.tools.Frameworks.withPrepare(Frameworks.java:150)
        at org.apache.calcite.tools.Frameworks.withPlanner(Frameworks.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.logicalPlan(CalcitePlanner.java:1414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.getOptimizedAST(CalcitePlanner.java:1430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.genOPTree(CalcitePlanner.java:450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:12161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:659)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1826)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1773)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1768)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.compileAndRespond(ReExecDriver.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236).
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a late answer, but I did run into the same issue. In my case, I found that the `hive-exec` Maven artifact's jar file is shading the Google collections framework. Now, since I've seen that other Hadoop/Hive artifacts also make use of Google Guava (version 11 if I'm not mistaken), there's a good chance that calcite will find the wrong class definition for `ImmutableSortedMap` (from Guava 11).

For me, excluding guava from the Hadoop/Hive artifacts that my code uses made calcite find the correct class version from Google collections.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
    <version>${hive.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${hive.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This is probably an issue that should be reported to the Hive project, since these kinds of class path collision errors are hard to diagnose. Internally shaded artifacts should have the project's own package prefix to indicate explicit shading of the external code in question.

Oh well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Jesus, did you rebuild hive from source? Did you update/exclude guava from every pom that mentions 'hive-exec'?

Comment: I tried this solution... it doesn't work unfortunately. In all the examples i've seen online of hive on windows, I haven't seen any implementation where the user can select abd from sometable