# Hive select problems: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have hadoop3.1.2 with hive 3.1.2 on win10, the problem is whenever I use select command or other functions to tables I got below errors and cli stops running, any help is grateful.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedMap does not implement the requested interface java.util.NavigableMap
        at org.apache.calcite.schema.Schemas.gatherLattices(Schemas.java:498)
        at org.apache.calcite.schema.Schemas.getLatticeEntries(Schemas.java:492)
        at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteConnectionImpl.init(CalciteConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver$1.onConnectionInit(Driver.java:109)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:139)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at org.apache.calcite.tools.Frameworks.withPrepare(Frameworks.java:150)
        at org.apache.calcite.tools.Frameworks.withPlanner(Frameworks.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.logicalPlan(CalcitePlanner.java:1414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.getOptimizedAST(CalcitePlanner.java:1430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.genOPTree(CalcitePlanner.java:450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:12164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:659)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1826)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1773)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1768)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.compileAndRespond(ReExecDriver.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.run(ReExecDriver.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:402)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477584/hive-crashing-with-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1468538/query-error-hive-3-1-1-with-hadoop-3-1-2-on-window10

Comment: `IncompatibleClassChangeError` suggests a version mismatch in dependencies, and namespace `com.google.common.*` usually points to _guava.jar_